# c# application with mysqldatabase uses a lot of ram

Tags: c#, mysql

I developed a point of sale application in C#, for DBMS i am using MySQL (Version 8.0.12), when i open Task Manager under process i see that mysqld is using 470MB of memory, so my question is what can i do to lower the ram usage and my other question is can i create a C# or in other language a script that will refresh my connection and clear the memory, please help.

P.S Here is how some of my code looks:

```
  public void NajavaTimeST()
    {
        var connection = Connection.prevzemiKonekcija();


        connection.Open();
        var dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

        try
        {
            var cmd =
                new MySqlCommand("UPDATE vraboteni SET poslednaNajava=@poslednaNajava WHERE korisnik =@korisnik",
                    connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@poslednaNajava", dt);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@korisnik", textBoxKorisnickoIme.Text);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code you have show should not be much of a problem unless you call it in rapid succession, many many times. You should `Dispose()` of  the Command too. Whatever is using the memory is elsewhere any you can see for yourself with the memory profiler built into Visual Studio.

Comment: how many times are you calling "NajavaTimeST" method? ,make sure you are not calling it recursively some where inside method or infinity while loops etc

Comment: 470MB for the sql server process isn't _that_ much. How much memory does your client application use? How much do you have available?

Comment: Nobody here will _guess_ the _right_ architecture for you. Only you know your "point of sale" application usage context. Is this a single POS machine? If so, did you consider other light(er)weight DBs? SQLite? Or is your app handling 1000s of POS clients (client/server)? Your question has nothing to do with "language" nor "script".